# Angular function not updating

Tags: jquery, angularjs

New to angular, i was advised not to use angular with jquery, however, i still need to use jquery sometimes just because it is more handy. basically, i build a function get a list of comment

```
    function showComment(){
        app.controller("commentController", function($scope,$http) {
            var url="/attraction/commentlist";
            var formData = {id:"1"};
            var postData = "data="+JSON.stringify(formData);
            $http.post(url,postData).success(function(response) {
                if(response!=false){
                    if(response.length==0){
                        $("#commenTable").hide();
                    }else{
                        $scope.comments = response;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

and then i want to recall this function when i get data using jquery

```
            $.ajax({url: "/attraction/addcomment", type:"post",data:form.serialize(), success: function(result){
                alert("haha");
                showComment();
                $("#attractioncomment-comment").val("");
                $("#attractioncomment-captcha").val("");
                $.get("/attraction/captcha",{"refresh":1},function(data){
                    $("#attractioncomment-captcha-image").attr("src",data.url);
                });
            }});
```

It is failing, the `showcomment()` is not updating with the newest entry. Please help.

Comment: why do you declare controller in function ??

Comment: i know it is not very property, but this is the way i can work at the moment.

Comment: For image, there is a directive `ng-src`, you can bind the image src with `<img ng-src="theUrlFromServer">`, then in your callback function of $.get, you just set the value `$scope.theUrlFromServer = data.url;`

Answer (score 0):

In your showComment() function, you just defined the controller, but it is never be functioned. You should define the controller in angular way, and use it on some DOM, or with route.

And some points:
 1. are you creating a controller in showComment() function? I never see that kind of usage, is that controller working properly?
 2. You should use data binding of angularjs to fill comment data, but not set val() in jquery way.
 3. You should use ng-show to show/hide something, but not jquery way.
 4. Should use $http.get() or post().

The only reason you should keep using jquery is, some js plugin or packages will use jquery, and you want to use them directly without creating some directives.

Comment: understand, but majority of my codes are in jquery, i only want to use bind data part for angular, so i can loop through comment template

Comment: I understand tat situation. I mean, it is very easy to bind data, just get the data with $http.get, and bing the var from returned data.

Comment: in this case which var should i bind for the returned data

Answer (score 0):

That's not how controllers work, friend. You shouldn't be directly executing controllers as functions. Try something more like

```
  app.controller("commentController", function($scope,$http) {

  // Create a function inside the controller
  function showComment() {
    var url="/attraction/commentlist";
    var formData = {id:"1"};
    var postData = "data="+JSON.stringify(formData);
    $http.post(url,postData).success(function(response) {
      if(response !== false){
        if(response.length === 0){
          $("#commenTable").hide();
        }else{
          $scope.comments = response;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  // Execute the function
  showComment();
});
```

I haven't really checked the rest of your code, but that's up to you.

Comment: i dont have problem to get commentController working at the moment, my problem is when i did ajax post and get the data, i cant call the showcomment to reflect the changes

Comment: The problem of your code is the way that you define the controller, you try to redefine the controller in `showCommen()`. The controller has a scope to bind the html element and angular controller, and all of them are maintained by angular framework. You can not define controller like that.